# option/header for client-name when using php imap_open or using plain imap protocol?

Tags: php, imap

I'd like to sent a client-name to the imap-server.

Is this possible with php [imap_open](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-open.php) (I didn't find a parameter-option in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-open.php)) or using the plain imap protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Client/server information is passed through the ID extension, which does not seem to be supported by the PHP library.

If you wish to use the base implementation, it is described in [RFC 2971](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2971.txt).  The server must advertise `ID` in its `CAPABILITY` response to use this.

Roughly, it is a command that takes a list of pairs of keys and values to pass various information:

```
tag ID ("name" "my awesome imap client" "version" "1.0")
```

Alternatively, perhaps you mean in messages.  Messages submitted through `SMTP` and `IMAP APPEND` often have a X-Mailer header, but this is certainly not universal.